# How can I display the user url input as a thumbnail?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, url

I want to take from the user an image URL and on submit display a thumbnail of that image in the same page
Here is how i take the URL from the user

```
<%= form_for([@project, @project.uploads.build]) do |f| %>
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :url %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :url %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

then i display the URL in the same page

```
<p>
  <%= upload.url %>  |

  <%= link_to 'Delete', [upload.project, upload],
            :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
            :method => :delete %> 
</p>
```

But instead i want to display a thumbnail..How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

image_tag is the Rails method you're looking for.  (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag).  Just use the uploaded URL as the source.  Then, use either the :size option, or set a class on your image tag and handle resizing it through CSS.

That method will of course not resize the actual image, and the user's browser will pull-down the larger file and then resize it in the browser.  It consumes the same amount of bandwidth as the full-size version, because it is the full-size version.

To do post-processing on the image and actually resize it (a real thumbnail), I recommend the CarrierWave Gem (https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave).  It's documentation is pretty good, so I won't dive into how to use it here.